# How to place some lines in the foreground and others in background?

Tags: jqplot

I need that some data line overlay the others without changing the order in jqplot. How can i do that?

```
plot1 = $.jqplot("chart1", [line1foreground,line2background,line3foreground, line4background,line5background], plotOptions)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`moveSeriesToFront`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.moveSeriesToFront) method.